# Test a void method with conditioned loop using mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have following method which asks for user input until valid user credentials are entered.It then generates id for that user and sets registered =TRUE.

1.How can I check the value of local variable "registered" from my unit test?

2.How can I assert in my test that while loop executed until "registered" became TRUE?

```
private void register() {

    boolean registered=false;
    while(!registered){
        try {
            String uname =this.read("User Name : ");
            char password[] = this.readPassword();
            String serverURL = this.read("Server URL : ");

            if(!uname.isEmpty() && password!=null && !serverURL.isEmpty()){ 

                registered=this.getUID(uname,password,serverURL);
            }
            if(registered==false)
                System.out.println("\nPlease verify your details and try again!\n");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {} 
        catch(Exception e){}    
    }
    System.out.println("Successful");
}
```

I have come across usage of ArgumentCaptor to capture variables that a method to be tested, uses to invoke another methods.

```
e.g verify(mockObj).intArgumentMethod(argument.capture());
```

However I am not passing variable "registered" to any other method otherwise i would have captured it.

Comment: You could verify it using [reflections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html). I think for that you would have to make it a class level variable and not a method variable. Not sure of that.

Comment: I will need to make it a class variable in that case,however that is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot
2. By verification:

   - The loop invariant is that `registered` is false. So the loop is not entered if it is true
   - The loop is exited

     - at the bodies start (in this case it is true)
     - if a Throwable is thrown, that is not caught by 'catch(Exception e)' (in this case it might be anything)

**Anyway - review your testing strategy:**

- a function has input parameters and output parameters
- the input should be part of the fixture:

  ```
  this.read("User Name : ")
  this.readPassword()
  this.read("Server URL : ")
  this.getUID(uname,password,serverURL) // this may also be viewed as output
  ```
- the output should be part of the assertions

  ```
  System.out.println(...)
  ```

The input can be set up by creating anonymous sub classes, e.g.

```
fixture = new YourClass {
  public String read(String prompt) {
    return mockedString;
  }
  ...
};
```

The output can be captured/asserted by a Junit Rule, e.g. [StandardErrorStreamLog](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/index.html#StandardErrorStreamLog)

Mockito is not needed with this example method.

Comment: Thanks @StefanA I could test positive scenario using  StandardErrorStreamLog as follows :  Whitebox.invokeMethod(pc,"register);
assertEquals("Successful\n", log.getLog()) .How can i test that while loop executed cetain number of times?

Comment: to test `register` you do not need `Whitebox`. Just set the method public. Assertions on the number of loop steps should not be subject to a unit test. However you could setup your input in a way that it will step multiple times. You can utilize `TextFromStandardInputStream` to simulate your user input - or just use the solution with anonymous subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't test the implementation details, test the behavior given certain input. If the `registered` variable is supposed to be some sort of output then it shouldn't be a local variable.

One design I like is to use method objects, it is possible to pass arguments at object creation, and an object method can have multiple return values.

```
class Registrator {
    Registrator(...) { /* assigning needed field */ }

    void register() { /* logic that will mutate internal fields */ }

    boolean registered() { return registered; }
    long triesCount() { return triesCount; }
    // ...
}
```

And one can adapt the code to use a `Report` object, on which the register method can append success / failure / more details like reasons / etc.

And the test would be much more easy to write.